# TYPO3 8.x backend panels resizable

Tags: typo3, backend

Is it possible to make backend panels resizable again, like in 7.x and below?
I mean left module menu and pagetree. And I'm not talking about collapse button, but specifically about mouse resize. Is there any option or extension to restore this functionality in any way? It really makes me angry now.

Comment: Use this extension: https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/pagetree_resizable/

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible and the reasons for removing those besides a complete new implentations are:

- People didn't find ways to reshow modules when resized
- Not possible on mobile as there is no drag'n'drop.

You can however open a feature request at https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues